# How do I properly encode a form in php

Tags: php, forms, character-encoding, decode, encode

On [my site](http://otherwords.info) users can add content to the database via a form. I want the users to be able to type anything in the form and for it all to be added to the database how they have entered it. At the moment I'm getting problems with a number of characters, namely slashes, &, ? etc.

What is the best way to allow all characters to be added to the database correctly?

Also, do you have to decode them when displaying them for it to work correctly? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: There's no need for any encoding. You can insert any character into the database as long as you run the correct escaping method on the data. For the `mysql_*` family of functions, that is `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Show the code you're using to input and output data, and describe what goes wrong at which point exactly.

Comment: What database are you using?  What character set are your databases/tables created using in the DDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving, use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) (or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)) to protect against SQL injection attacks. This will make it possible to write quotes and backslashes without destroying the SQL query.

```
<?php
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table(text) VALUES("'.$text.'")');
?>
```

When printing the data to a browser (with echo), first run it through [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to disable HTML and solve your current problem:

```
<?php
// ...fetch $text from db here...
echo htmlspecialchars($text);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) may help you encode and [decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) html characters:

You can also use [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to preserve line breaks from textarea elements:

Also you should use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) for your database needs as it is much more secure than the old method of escaping data, mysql_real_escape_string()